# How to retrive @Test method parameters in @DataProvider method?

Tags: testing, parameters, testng, test-data, testng-dataprovider

I would like to retrieve parameters name of Test method in DataProvider method. 
By using `method.getParameterTypes()` in DataProvider, I am able to get the class of param being passed in Test method, but I want the names.

```
@Test
public void TC_001(String userName, String passWord){
//code goes here
}

@DataProvider
public Object[][] testData(Method method){
//Here I want to get names of param of test method i.e. userName and passWord
}
```

This is required because using these names I can get the data from my Excel file

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get the parameters from the method to get the parameter names.

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] testData(Method method){
    String arg0 = method.getParameters()[0].getName();
    // should be "userName" in your example test case
}
```

Note that the classes have to be compiled with `-g:vars` to include the parameter names in the debug information. Otherwise parameter names are named `arg0`, `arg1`, ... It appears that with the OpenJDK 8 this is the default.

To be less dependant on that fact and to avoid possible name confusion/conflicts I'd use a (custom) annotation that specifies the argument name:

Define an annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(PARAMETER)
public @interface ParamName {
    public String value();
}
```

Use it:

```
public void TC_001(@ParamName("username") String userName, String passWord) { ... }
```

Access the name:

```
Parameter parameter = method.getParameters()[0];
ParamName parameterNameAnn = parameter[0].getAnnotation(ParamName.class);
String parameterName;

if (parameterNameAnn != null) {
    // get the annotated name
    parameterName = parameterNameAnn.value();
} else {
    // annotation missing, resort to the "reflected" name
    parameterName = parameter.getName();
}
```

See also

- [Reflection Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/index.html) (Oracle)
- Especially [Parameter Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html) (Oracle)
- [Compiler options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#standard) (Oracle)
- [Annotation Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html) (Oracle)